# Solving the equation $ \arccos \frac{1-x}{1+x} - \arcsin \frac{2 \sqrt{x}}{1+x} = 0 $

Tags: trigonometry

I need to solve the equation $$ \arccos \frac{1-x}{1+x} - \arcsin \frac{2 \sqrt{x}}{1+x} = 0, x \in \mathbb{R} $$
I put $ x = \tan^2(t)$, and it seemed to work. But it's not true for every $x$ in $ \mathbb{R} $. only for $[0, 1]$. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The range of $\tan(t)$ is all the real numbers.

Comment: $x=\tan^2 t$ would work a lot more nicely. This statement can't work for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ anyway because of the square root. $x$ needs to be positive.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to write $ x = tant^2(t) $. I know that $ x \geqslant 0 $ . But why is $ x \leqslant 1 $ ?

Comment: Hint: The range of $\arccos x$ is $[0,\pi]$, the range of $\arcsin x$ is $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. Their intersection is $[0,\pi/2]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [tangent half angle identites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula) with $x=\tan^2 \frac t2\ge 0$ as requested

$$\arccos \frac{1-x}{1+x} - \arcsin \frac{2 \sqrt{x}}{1+x} = 0 \iff \arccos (\cos t) - \arcsin (\sin t) = 0$$

then we have

- for $-\frac \pi 2 <t<0$

$$\arccos (\cos t) - \arcsin (\sin t) = -t-t=0 \implies t=0$$

- for $0\le t\le\frac \pi 2 $

$$\arccos (\cos t) - \arcsin (\sin t) = t-t=0 $$

- for $\frac \pi 2<t<\pi $

$$\arccos (\cos t) - \arcsin (\sin t) = t-(\pi -t)=0 \implies t=\frac \pi 2$$

- for $\pi \le t< \frac {3\pi} 2$

$$\arccos (\cos t) - \arcsin (\sin t) = -t-(\pi -t)=0 \implies \pi=0$$

- for $t= \pm\frac {\pi} 2$

$$\arccos (\cos t) - \arcsin (\sin t) = 0 \implies \mp\frac \pi 2=0 $$

therefore the solutions are $0\le t\le\frac \pi 2 \iff 0\le x \le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $1-x < 1+x$ and $2\sqrt{x}<1+x$, then $1-x$ and $2\sqrt{x}$ are the legs of a right triangle with hypotenuse $1+x$. When this happens, the equation will certainly be satisfied. The solution to these two inequalities with $x>0$ and $1-x>0$ is $x\in (0,1)$. The two endpoints $x=0$ and $x=1$ provide solutions as well.